# How to proceed with database statements

Tags: php, jquery, json

Using one of the tutorials I managed to create a working database retrieval using PHP, JSON and jQuery

Now my question is, if I have multiple query statements that I want to execute what is the best solution?

I have tried opening a second connection in different functions and sending the information as an array in array but that does not work.

**`database.php`:**

```
<?php

function getDbConnection() {
  $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USER);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
  return $db;
}
function home_ratings() {
    $db = getDbConnection();
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("select * from table1");

    $isOk1 = $stmt1->execute();

     $results_home = array();

     if ($isOk1) 
        {
            $results_home = $stmt1->fetchAll();
        } 
    else 
        {
            trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    $db = null; 
    return $results_home;

}
?>
```

**`get.php`:**

```
<?php
require('constant.php');
require('database.php');

$home = home_ratings();
//$top_rest = top_ratings();
//$newr = new_ratings();

//echo json_encode($home);
echo json_encode(array('home' => $home));
?>
```

**`info.js`:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.get( "php/get.php")
    .done(function(data) {  
                    var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    $.each(results, function(i, value) {
                    //do what i need to do here
                   })
                }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one database connection object if you're connecting to the same database in the same method. Instead of having a function for `getDbConnection()` instead make the `$db` variable global and use it within functions (you may need to put a line `global $db;` in the function to ensure that it can access the global variable).

**Example of how your `database.php` file could look:**

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USER);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

function home_ratings() {
    global $db; // $db scope of global
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("select * from table1");

    $isOk1 = $stmt1->execute();

     $results_home = array();

     if ($isOk1) 
        {
            $results_home = $stmt1->fetchAll();
        } 
    else 
        {
            trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }

    return $results_home;
}
?>
```

Comment: I created a second function with the proposed solution. As long as i use identical statements in both functions it works, once i've changed one of them it does not. What am i missing here?

Comment: @user1805445 I've updated my answer with an example of how your `database.php` file could look if you made `$db` a global variable rather than a function call. I hope that helps.

Comment: yea , i already done that as i was instructed earlier. The problem is once ive created a second function duplicating the first one just changing the statement query it fails. Additionally, ive tried to close the first statement before creating the new one but still nothing happens

Comment: @user1805445 What do you mean by you've tried to close the first statement? Show me the new code please on pastebin or something.

Comment: $stmt1->close(); , but i do not think my problem lies in the database.php but where the json is located in get.php

Comment: @user1805445 You shouldn't need to close the statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83536/discussion-between-user1805445-and-em-creations).

Comment: @user1805445 I can't unfortunately at the moment, my work firewall blocks StackOverflow's chat.

Comment: Its alright , ill close thediscussion and move it to JSON as its fully json related. The problem lies when json encodes more than one function. Thank you for all your help